# How can I get dictionary size of 7z archive using comand line?

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip, 7za

I've got an 7z archive, I've read manuals but couldn't find how can I get dictionary size of this archive using comandline?

Answer (score 0):

There's no command-line option in 7zip to give you this information from the command-line, at least not with 7-zip version 9.20.

Comment: Ok. but how can I detect this information in hex dump?

Comment: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BJOERN/Compress-Deflate7-1.0/7zip/DOC/7zFormat.txt describes the format but I don't see the dictionary size explicitly specified. You may have to dive into the source code. Regardless, this is off-topic for this forum.